# Creating a multiple choice form for each primary key in model with Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a class registration app in Django. To simplify my problem, I have a model for students, blocks (time periods), and classes (lessons). There are multiple classes for each block, and students must register in exactly 1 class for each block. There will be some customization allowed, so it is not known in advance how many blocks there are or which classes are available for each block.

I want to generate a form with radio buttons that looks like this:

---

#### Block A (9:00 - 11:00)

- Django class for beginners
- Some other class
- Yet another class

#### Block B (11:00 - 13:00)

- Class for something
- How to math
- Placeholder class

...

#### Block E (16:00 - 17:30)

- Choice 1
- Choice 2
- Choice 3
- Choice 4

---

Currently, my models look something like this:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    [...]

class Block(models.Model):
    block = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True,
        choices=(('A', 'Block A'),
                 ('B', 'Block B'),
                 ('C', 'Block C'),
                 ('D', 'Block D'),
                 ('E', 'Block E')))
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    [...]

class Class(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    block = models.ForeignKey('Block')
    [...]
```

So far, I have something like this in my `forms.py`:

```
class ClassForm(Form):
    class_choice = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Class.objects.all(),
        widget=RadioSelect,
        empty_label=None)
```

And I can serve that form in my `views.py`, but of course it just lists all the available classes for each block.

I think I need to loop over all the existing blocks and filter the lessons for each block iteration and list it as a multiple choice form, but I am unsure what the best way is to approach the problem, and then how to record the class choices for each block for each student.

Comment: why do you need multiple choice form when one user is allowed to enroll for one class per block ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I would use the django forms framework for this. Instead you can build the html form directly in the template and process the POST data in the view. Html `radiobutton` elements with the same `name` attribute. ("Block A", "Block B", etc) work kind of like a single input element, and will have a single value result.

Comment: If you want to use the django forms framework, you can look into FormSets. With one Form instance for each Block. To represent the signups in your database, create a m2m relation between Student and Block, with an intermediate model that contains the relation to Class as well. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: @HåkenLid Thank you for your comment, I think using FormSets and a m2m relationship is a push in the right direction. I am still a bit new to django so I am trying to find my bearings.